# Change an attribute for a tree of items in Rational Team Concert

Tags: rtc

We use RTC for planning. We create Epics, Stories as their children, Tasks as Story children etc. Often, we need to change something for the whole story and its sub-tasks, e.g. the Iteration planned. Is there a way to change the attribute for the whole tree (following "child" type of links), so we won't need to go and change one by one?

I haven't found anything in the documentation nor online...

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can perform multiple Work ITems (WI) changes through the "Work Items" views which display the result of a Query: select multiple lines, right-click on the right column (the one with the values you want to change), and you will have the other values for that attribute for you to select.

So if you can manage to make a *query* which select the right work items, you can do what you need.
The ["`Parent>ID is`" criteria](https://jazz.net/forum/questions/80411/rtc-query-based-on-parent-id-not-finding-any-matches) is one way, but might be limited to only one level though.

Comment: Even if it is not ideal, this is probably the only way how to change multiple items at once with RTC 3.0.x we've got right now. Also, I wasn't able to come up with a query that will return the whole tree... I guess not possible.